# C++ constructor overloading error unable to match function definition

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, overloading

I am using Microsoft Visual Studios and I have create a generic class List_Array. There is no problem with the default constructor, but the other two (overloaded) constructors are generating the error.

```
//List_Array.h

template<typename T>
class List_Array {
private:
     int size; ...
     T* data;
public:
     List_Array<T>::List_Array();
     List_Array<T>::List_Array(int);
     List_Array<T>::List_Array(const T&, int);
     ...
};

template<typename T>
List_Array<T>::List_Array() { }

template<typename T>
List_Array<T>::List_Array(int s) {
     this->size = s
     this->data = new T[s];
}

template<typename T>
List_Array<T>::List_Array(const T& init, int s){
     this->size = s;
     this->data = new T[s];
     for (int i = 0; i < s; i++){
          this->data[i] = init;
     }
}
```

I get a C2244 'List_Array::List_Array': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with template or overloading. You just don't need `List_Array<T>::` part for the member function declaration inside class definition. i.e.

```
template<typename T>
class List_Array {
private:
     int size; ...
     T* data;
public:
     List_Array();
     List_Array(int);
     List_Array(const T&, int);
     ...
};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/XMJIU70665)

Comment: Thank You! I didn't realize that would cause a problem.

Comment: @TylerHughes Note this is true for non-template classes too. So the issue has nothing to do with template and overloading here.